# Making std::variant type tools work with types inhereted from std::variant

Tags: c++

With C++23, we're entering the era of [Inheriting from std::variant](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2162r0.html). So we can write types derived of, and expanding the functionality of variants. Example:

```cpp
struct State : std::variant<int, float>
{
   using variant::variant;
}
```

This now acts like a `std::variant` and I can add member functions etc. But unfortunately, many tools for `std::variant` don't work with this inherited type anymore. Neither `std::variant_size` nor `std::variant_alternative` or the common implementation of `is_alternative`.

My template-fu isn't good enough to fix this. Is there a way?

TLDR: With the type above, make `static_assert(std::variant_size_v<State> == 2);` work

Comment: Just `template<> struct std::variant_size<State> : std::variant_size<State::variant> {};` ?

Comment: That works, thanks. But if I may: How does `State::variant` work? what is variant in that context? Can you refer to the base class in that way?

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name. You already used the same construct in `using variant::variant`.